# Android Nested Recycler Views

Tags: android, json, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have 2 recycler views in my android app, as illustrated in the image below:[image]

One is actually a parent of the other. The child is the area with squares which in the real sense should be images. Now, I have a problem with setting the adapter of the child, which holds the images.
This is what I'm trying so far on the 'parent' adapter:

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.feed_list_row, parent, false);

        // Set the view to the ViewHolder
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);

        holder.mHorizontalListView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        holder.mHorizontalListView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        // use a grid layout manager
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(parent.getContext(), 3);
        holder.mHorizontalListView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FeedItem feedItem = feedItems.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(feedItem.getName());
        holder.timestamp.setText(feedItem.getTimeStamp());
        holder.profilePic.setImageUrl(feedItem.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        List<FeedPhoto> feedItemPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

        feedPhotosAdapter = new FeedPhotosAdapter(mContext, feedItemPhotos);
        holder.mHorizontalListView.setAdapter(feedPhotosAdapter);
        feedPhotosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I'm stuck at getting the json data for the child adapter. The whole JSON I'm getting from my API look like:

```
{
  "feed": [
    {
      "username": "denny",
      "profile_pic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/lincoln.jpg",
      "name": "Denny Wayne",
      "timestamp": "1403375851930",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "http://scontent-a-fra.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/10665483_429615813855717_1490926670_n.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "http://scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/10891026_694434897342602_1094773634_n.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "http://scontent-a-fra.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/10894920_1382218332084671_10354293_n.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "username": "denny",
      "profile_pic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/discovery.jpg",
      "name": "Denny Wainaina",
      "timestamp": "1403375851930",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "http://scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/10895429_768163716566132_692639371_n.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "http://scontent-b-fra.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/10899087_405295322969722_20422376_n.jpg"
        },
        {
          "url": "http://scontent-a-fra.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s306x306/e15/10899123_922231267802027_1123900984_n.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem I think you need to implement the Expandable RecyclerView
use :

```
 compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.0.3'
```

Expandable RecyclerView as the name suggests the view can be expanded which has its own child views inside
check the external library here

[Expandable RecyclerView on Github](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view#expandable-recyclerview)